# Vue & Firebase class binding

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuefire

New to both Vue & Firebase here.  I'm prototyping an app that has a matrix of buttons that I'd like for all users across devices to be able to see which buttons are "active" by applying a css class to the button when the database has changed.  I'm using [VueFire](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire) to bind the Firebase reference with Vue.

At first I tried something like this but it didn't work and I feel like it's probably not the right way to do it anyway.

HTML

```
<button v-bind:class='{ "active": buttons['button1'] }'>                
<button v-bind:class='{ "active": buttons['button2'] }'>                
<button v-bind:class='{ "active": buttons['button3'] }'>
<button v-bind:class='{ "active": buttons['button4'] }'>
```

Then, I thought I'd be able to use a method to determine if the button is active based on its name but it is not working either.

HTML

```
<button v-bind:class='{ "active": isBtnActive("button1") }'>                
<button v-bind:class='{ "active": isBtnActive("button2") }'>                
<button v-bind:class='{ "active": isBtnActive("button3") }'>
<button v-bind:class='{ "active": isBtnActive("button4") }'>
```

Javascript

```
var buttonsRef = firebase.database().ref('buttons');

var app = new Vue({ 
    el: '#app',
    data: {
    },
    firebase: {
        buttons: buttonsRef
    },  
    methods: {      
        isBtnActive: function(name) {           
            return buttonsRef.child(name);              
        }
    }
});
```

Firebase data as JSON

```
{
    "buttons": {
        "button1": false,
        "button2": false,
        "button3": false,
        "button4": false
    }   
}
```

What am I missing?  I seems like this should be straight forward functionality.

Comment: is `buttonsRef.child` a valid method? Or is `buttonsRef` just an Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on that database structure, `this.buttons` will look something like this:

```
[ { ".value": true, ".key": "button1" }, { ".value": false, ".key": "button2" }, { ".value": false, ".key": "button3" }, { ".value": true, ".key": "button4" } ]
```

That being the case, your `isBtnActive` method should look like this:

```
isBtnActive(btn){
  const button = this.buttons.find(b => b[".key"] === btn)
  if (button) return {active: button[".value"]}
  else return {active: false}
}
```

Alternatively you could retrieve `buttons` as an object.

```
firebase: {
  buttons: {
    source: buttonsRef,
    asObject: true,
  }
},
```

And change your method to

```
isBtnActive(btn){
  return { active: this.buttons[btn]}
}
```

Or omit the method altogether.

```
<button :class="{active: buttons['button3']}">Button 3</button>
```

Comment: Thanks!  It works.  I appreciate your alternative method as well, very nice.